# Regex to remove new lines up to a specific character

Tags: python, regex, fasta

I have a series of strings in a file of the format:

```
>HEADER_Text1
Information here, yada yada yada
Some more information here, yada yada yada
Even some more information here, yada yada yada
>HEADER_Text2
Information here, yada yada yada
Some more information here, yada yada yada
Even some more information here, yada yada yada
>HEADER_Text3
Information here, yada yada yada
Some more information here, yada yada yada
Even some more information here, yada yada yada
```

I am trying to find a regex pattern which will remove the new line characters below the `>` character in between the next `>` character. So the final result would look like:

```
>HEADER_Text1
Information here, yada yada yada Some more information here, yada yada yada Even some more information here, yada yada yada
>HEADER_Text2
Information here, yada yada yada Some more information here, yada yada yada Even some more information here, yada yada yada
>HEADER_Text3
Information here, yada yada yada Some more information here, yada yada yada Even some more information here, yada yada yada
```

Does anyone know how I can come up with a regex pattern to do this?

Side note: This format is common in computational science as a FASTA format.

Thanks!

Comment: There are good Python parsers for FASTA format, you don't need to implement one yourself. Consider using [BioPython](http://biopython.org/) if you do genomics and [pyteomics](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyteomics) (which I develop) if you do proteomics. Both will do the parsing fine, but they have other features that are more field-specific.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, your best bet is to use an existing FASTA parser.  Why not?

Here's how I would join lines based on the leading greater-than:

```
def joinup(f):
    buf = []
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if buf:
                yield " ".join(buf)
            yield line.rstrip()
            buf = []
        else:
            buf.append(line.rstrip())
    yield " ".join(buf)

for joined_line in joinup(open("...")):
    # blah blah...
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the > is always expected to be the first character on the new line

"\n([^>])" with " \1"

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use regex:

```
[ x.startswith('>') and x or x.replace('\n','') for x in f.readlines()]
```

should work.

```
In [43]: f=open('test.txt')

In [44]: contents=[ x.startswith('>') and x or x.replace('\n','') for x in f.readlines()]                                                                                   

In [45]: contents
Out[45]: 
['>HEADER_Text1\n',
 'Information here, yada yada yada',
 'Some more information here, yada yada yada',
 'Even some more information here, yada yada yada',
 '>HEADER_Text2\n',
 'Information here, yada yada yada',
 'Some more information here, yada yada yada',
 'Even some more information here, yada yada yada',
 '>HEADER_Text3\n',
 'Information here, yada yada yada',
 'Some more information here, yada yada yada',
 'Even some more information here, yada yada yada']
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the OP's question, which is about joining the lines not starting with `>`.

Comment: If you do a simple adjustment - make lines that start with > also have a `\n` before then, and then join and trim it WILL answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

this should also work.

sampleText=""">HEADER_Text1
Information here, yada yada yada
Some more information here, yada yada yada
Even some more information here, yada yada yada

> HEADER_Text2
>   Information here, yada yada yada
>   Some more information here, yada yada yada
>   Even some more information here, yada yada yada
>   HEADER_Text3
>   Information here, yada yada yada
>   Some more information here, yada yada yada
>   Even some more information here, yada yada yada""""

cleartext = re.sub ("\n(?!>)", "", sampleText)

print cleartext

> HEADER_Text1Information here, yada yada yadaSome more information here, yada yada yadaEven some more information here, yada yada yada
>   HEADER_Text2Information here, yada yada yadaSome more information here, yada yada yadaEven some more information here, yada yada yada
>   HEADER_Text3Information here, yada yada yadaSome more information here, yada yada yadaEven some more information here, yada yada yada

Comment: It is hard given the formatting of your answer to pinpoint what you're proposing the answer is.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want a regex. And for this job, python and biopython are superfluous. If that's actually FASTQ format, just use `sed`:

```
sed '/^>/ { N; N; N; s/\n/ /2g }' file
```

Results:

```
>HEADER_Text1
Information here, yada yada yada Some more information here, yada yada yada Even some more information here, yada yada yada
>HEADER_Text2
Information here, yada yada yada Some more information here, yada yada yada Even some more information here, yada yada yada
>HEADER_Text3
Information here, yada yada yada Some more information here, yada yada yada Even some more information here, yada yada yada
```