# Compiling lines from file that are separated by a certain element . Python

Tags: python, function, indexing, line, fasta

File:

```
>1
ATTTTttttGGGG
ccCgCgGAgggGGT
gggggttttTTTTTTTTT
>2
ATcggGGGGGGA
>3
ATCGGGGGGATTT
gggggttAGTAttt
```

i'm constructing a function that reads files that have this format.
the format has multiple files embedded in it that are separated by '>'+the name (e.g. '>1','>2')

i'm trying to get the lines of text flanked by the '>' lines and compile them into one string per section

so this would look like

```
name_list = ['>1','>2','>3']
sequence_list = ['ATTTTttttGGGGccCgCgGAgggGGTgggggttttTTTTTTTTT','ATcggGGGGGGA','ATCGGGGGGATTTgggggttAGTAttt']

import os
import re

# Open File

in_file=open(FASTA,'r')
dir,file=os.path.split(FASTA)
temp = os.path.join(dir,output)
out_file=open(temp,'w')

# Generating lines

lines = []
name_list = []
seq_list = []

for line in in_file:
    line = line.strip()
    lines.append(line)

in_file.close()

indx = range(0,len(lines))

# Organizing the elements
for line in lines:
    for i in line:
        if i == '>':
            name_list.append(line)
        else:
            break
```

I don't know what to do for the else: statement
I tried creating an index with range(0,len(lines))
so maybe i could do something where it finds '>' and compile all lines for the following indices until it finds the next '>' and adds them to the list called seq_list

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe I'm not catching all the requirements here, but can you just split on lines that start with `>`?

Comment: Please take a look at my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800970/regex-to-remove-new-lines-up-to-a-specific-character#comment20728952_14800970). In a nutshell: FASTA parsers are the wheel already invented, you don't need to waste time on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary would make life easier:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> with open('t.txt') as f:
...   for line in f:
...      if line.startswith('>'):
...         key = line.strip()
...         if key not in d:
...             d[key] = []
...      else:
...         d[key].append(line.strip())
... 
>>> d
{'>1': ['ATTTTttttGGGG', 'ccCgCgGAgggGGT', 'gggggttttTTTTTTTTT'],
 '>2': ['ATcggGGGGGGA'], '>3': ['ATCGGGGGGATTT', 'gggggttAGTAttt']}
>>> sequence_list = [''.join(k) for k in d.values()]
>>> sequence_list
['ATTTTttttGGGGccCgCgGAgggGGTgggggttttTTTTTTTTT',
 'ATcggGGGGGGA', 'ATCGGGGGGATTTgggggttAGTAttt']
```

Comment: Then you could get the two lists out (if that's what's needed) by d.keys() and d.values()

Comment: what about combining the elements in d.values ?

Comment: i'm trying to make it as fast as possible, is there any way to concatenate the strings in the else: line ?

Comment: Instead of `d[key] = []` do `d[key] = ""`, and instead of `d[key].append(line.strip())` do `d[key] = d[key] + line.strip()`

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) that has a `FASTA` parser, but here's an example using the standard lib:

```
import re
with open('filename') as f:
    print [i.replace('\n','') for i in re.split(r'\>\d+',f.read()) if i]
```

out:

```
['ATTTTttttGGGGccCgCgGAgggGGTgggggttttTTTTTTTTT',
 'ATcggGGGGGGA',
 'ATCGGGGGGATTTgggggttAGTAttt']
```

---

Using `Biopython` [`sudo pip install biopython`]:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
with open("example.fasta", "rU") as handle:
    print list(SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"))
```

out:

```
[SeqRecord(seq=Seq('ATTTTttttGGGGccCgCgGAgggGGTgggggttttTTTTTTTTT', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='1', name='1', description='1', dbxrefs=[]), 
 SeqRecord(seq=Seq('ATcggGGGGGGA', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='2', name='2', description='2', dbxrefs=[]),
 SeqRecord(seq=Seq('ATCGGGGGGATTTgggggttAGTAttt', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='3', name='3', description='3', dbxrefs=[])]
```

Comment: i tried installing BioPython but i was having trouble getting it to work on my machine

Comment: @draconisthe0ry -- did you use `pip`?