# Ordered changing of dictionary keys (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I know it is possible to change the keys in a dictionary. But is it possible to change all the keys using a defined pattern? In this case I have a dictionary that contain:

```
{'>Apple': 'Orange', '>Grape': 'Hopz'}
```

**Question:** All key's contain a '>' + string. Can I remove these '>' and update? Or update without '>'?

**Little background:**
In my script I try to compare one dictionaries values to this examples keys which results in an error. I assume this is due to the '>' because v =! k if k = '>foo' and v = 'foo'

If any of you are scientist this '>' is a result of a fasta parser. Which I could probably just change the script to not write the '>' at the start of a line (I haven't tried this..yet).

Comment: When I see this kind of questions, I feel obliged to note: [there are decent FASTA parsers for Python available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800970/regex-to-remove-new-lines-up-to-a-specific-character#comment20728952_14800970).

Comment: True...but my question was not about the parser I had made. That was simply a potential solution that came to mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy enough with a dict comprehension:

```
updateddict = {k.lstrip('>'): v for k, v in yourdict.iteritems()}
```

for Python 2.7. For Python 3, use `yourdict.items()` instead.

For Python 2.6 and earlier, where there is no dict comprehension syntax yet, use:

```
updateddict = dict((k.lstrip('>'), v) for k, v in yourdict.iteritems())
```

[`str.lstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) is a quick and concise method to remove any `>` characters from the start of a key.

Comment: yourdict.items I can understand :P   But, ".lstrip" do i need to import something for this?

Comment: @jon_shep No, it's a string method.

Comment: Thank you guys! Always love the fast replies here about stuff my book wont teach me.